# issues pulling remote master branch on github

Tags: git, github, pull

I am trying to pull my remote master repository on github to my local machine so I can make changes and then push back to master, but I am getting the following error when I try to pull it to my local machine.

```
developer@Codys-MacBook-Pro-3:~/everest-web$ sudo git pull 
https://github.com/everest-software/everest-web.git
From https://github.com/everest-software/everest-web
* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Not sure what to do because it is critical that I have these my machine synced with github.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: can i post the log in here @JohnBaker?

Comment: Just make sure you don't post any sensitive information.

Comment: Its too long to post in here. Is there another way for me to link you the text?

Answer (score 0):

Locally you're in a repo, but it contains a history different from github.  How best to fix that depends on *why*.  You mention in comments that there's a long log - that suggests this repo represents the history of a project, which is presumably not the same project you're trying to sync with.  (If it *is* the same project, then you're going to need to figure out how you got two unrelated histories for the same project, and how you want to resolve that issue; but for now I'm continuing on the assumption that isn't the case.)

So the straightforward thing to do is, create a new local repo for this project.  You can do this with `git clone`, which will initialize a new repo for you and populate it with the github history.  (You don't really want to still be in the existing local repo when you do this.  Since I don't know how you organize things on your local computer, I can't say exactly where you should be; but for example if you have a directory where you keep your local repos, `cd` to that and then give the `git clone` command with your github URL.)

It is possible in a couple different ways to add a remote's history into an existing repo.  An alternative to `clone` is

```
git init
git remote origin add <github-url>
git pull
```

But this shouldn't cause the error you're seeing unless you create at least one commit after the `init` and before the `pull`.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I set up a local repository first. Then went to github and created a new repository. Then I ran

git remote add origin

When I tried to push/pull, I got the same fatal: unrelated_histories error. Here is how I fixed it:

git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
... add and commit here...
git push origin master

Comment: While this worked in user2852260's situation, it may be entirely inappropriate and cause significant problems if applied in other situations where the same error occurs.  Make sure you know what you're doing and why before following a procedure like this.